# I want to paste contents from my clipboard to an formated excel table

Tags: html, excel, vba

I need something to do that: I copy the element from an HTML and paste it in a excel table, respecting the formatting of my spreadsheet (rows and columns), so to be simple, i will create a macro to paste the contents tha are in my clipboard

I want that result [image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/AE6Tm.png]

Copying data from that table [![https://i.stack.imgur.com/uNhTT.png][2]][2]

And if it is possible, i want VBA to autodelete first and last row of the table that are in clipboard before pasting

I tried that

```
Sub COLAR()

Dim DataObj As MSForms.DataObject
Set DataObj = New MSForms.DataObject
DataObj.GetFromClipboard

SText = DataObj.GetText(1)

ActiveSheet.Range("A3:M90").Value = SText

End Sub
```

But didnt work, and i was getting that result

[![https://i.stack.imgur.com/TSSG9.png][3]][3]

Im extracting data from that html, just copying manually the elements in the page:

```html
<table class="ExcelTable2007" border="1" width="100%">
<tbody><tr bgcolor="#ffffff">
<th nowrap="nowrap" class="heading"><div style="resize: horizontal;overflow:auto;">Código</div></th>
<th nowrap="nowrap" class="heading"><div style="resize: horizontal;overflow:auto;">Item</div></th>
<th nowrap="nowrap" class="heading"><div style="resize: horizontal;overflow:auto;">Operação</div></th>
<th nowrap="nowrap" class="heading"><div style="resize: horizontal;overflow:auto;">Material</div></th>
<th nowrap="nowrap" class="heading"><div style="resize: horizontal;overflow:auto;">Un</div></th>
<th nowrap="nowrap" class="heading"><div style="resize: horizontal;overflow:auto;">Centro Custos</div></th>
<th nowrap="nowrap" class="heading"><div style="resize: horizontal;overflow:auto;">Quantidade</div></th>
<th nowrap="nowrap" class="heading"><div style="resize: horizontal;overflow:auto;">Unitário</div></th>
<th nowrap="nowrap" class="heading"><div style="resize: horizontal;overflow:auto;">Sub-Total</div></th>
<th nowrap="nowrap" class="heading"><div style="resize: horizontal;overflow:auto;">Impostos</div></th>
<th nowrap="nowrap" class="heading"><div style="resize: horizontal;overflow:auto;">Total</div></th>
<th nowrap="nowrap" class="heading"><div style="resize: horizontal;overflow:auto;">Apropriado</div></th>
<th nowrap="nowrap" class="heading"><div style="resize: horizontal;overflow:auto;">Obs</div></th>
<th nowrap="nowrap" class="heading"><div style="resize: horizontal;overflow:auto;"></div></th>
</tr>
<tr class="whiteThing" onmouseover="this.className='yellowThing';" onmouseout="this.className='whiteThing';"><td class="heading" align="left"><a href="JavaScript:Editar_Aux('formulario_aux','ALTERAR','53200','9014','','633','1','1','2,0000','535,56000','937,19','DECA','28162')">[Editar] </a><a href="JavaScript:impostoItem('.1384.0Zl3Dk1Iew8_Hgn4fXqi3tSw','.799.5Rr2Tx6Mu553Qn290Rm09','.1555.2Ce1Dl0CuD1GIgT3IVfM6PTsN3IGp')"> <img width="16" height="16" alt="Impostos" title="Impostos" style="cursor:pointer;border:0px;" src="imagens/internas/AC_TAX.PNG">&nbsp;<span>Impostos</span></a></td><td>1</td><td>1101-COMPRAS</td><td>9014-CUBA DE APOIO RETANGULAR COM MESA L7300.17 NBR 15097-1</td><td>Un</td><td>011.001.01-LOUÇAS E METAIS</td><td align="right">2,0000</td><td align="right">535,56000</td><td align="right">1.071,12</td><td align="right">-133,93</td><td align="right">937,19</td><td><em></em></td><td>DECA</td><td></td></tr><tr class="whiteThing" onmouseover="this.className='yellowThing';" onmouseout="this.className='whiteThing';"><td class="heading" align="left"><a href="JavaScript:Editar_Aux('formulario_aux','ALTERAR','53201','2262','','633','1','1','230,0000','65,18000','12734,07','DECA','28162')">[Editar] </a><a href="JavaScript:impostoItem('.1368.4Wq0Sr0Lzw8_Rzn6fKti1tBe','.778.9Cd1Eg1Vg563Oc220Lv13','.1566.9Oa5Vo4QhD9GEcT2IVvM4PNyN3IQd')"> <img width="16" height="16" alt="Impostos" title="Impostos" style="cursor:pointer;border:0px;" src="imagens/internas/AC_TAX.PNG">&nbsp;<span>Impostos</span></a></td><td>2</td><td>1101-COMPRAS</td><td>2262-CUBA DE EMBUTIR OVAL L37.17 BRANCA NBR 15097-1</td><td>Un</td><td>011.001.01-LOUÇAS E METAIS</td><td align="right">230,0000</td><td align="right">65,18000</td><td align="right">14.991,40</td><td align="right">-3.194,52</td><td align="right">11.796,88</td><td><em></em></td><td>DECA</td><td></td></tr><tr class="whiteThing" onmouseover="this.className='yellowThing';" onmouseout="this.className='whiteThing';"><td class="heading" align="left"><a href="JavaScript:Editar_Aux('formulario_aux','ALTERAR','53202','2250','','633','1','1','100,0000','50,99000','17195,50','DECA','28162')">[Editar] </a><a href="JavaScript:impostoItem('.1332.0Th6Fo8Nbw0_Ian3fJki5tRd','.772.9Yj4Gx4Eq543Jb250Ln29','.1589.7Fb0He5WpD8GZlT0IUlM9PTcN0IYq')"> <img width="16" height="16" alt="Impostos" title="Impostos" style="cursor:pointer;border:0px;" src="imagens/internas/AC_TAX.PNG">&nbsp;<span>Impostos</span></a></td><td>3</td><td>1101-COMPRAS</td><td>2250-PARAFUSO PARA FIXACAO DE TANQUE FT.11.01 CROMADO NBR 14162</td><td>Un</td><td>011.001.01-LOUÇAS E METAIS</td><td align="right">100,0000</td><td align="right">50,99000</td><td align="right">5.099,00</td><td align="right">-637,57</td><td align="right">4.461,43</td><td><em></em></td><td>DECA</td><td></td></tr><tr><td colspan="6"></td><td align="center"><em><a href="JavaScript:impostoItem('.1375.4El0Yz6Ptw9_Xrn1fMii6tJn','.789.3Yb1Xd3Gf533Vb250Xj09','.1571.4Vw2Ui6FcL7SXdT8IKfM3PXkN0FSa')"> <img width="16" height="16" alt="Impostos" title="Impostos" style="cursor:pointer;border:0px;" src="imagens/internas/AC_TAX.PNG">&nbsp;<span> Impostos</span></a></em></td><td align="right"><em>Soma:</em></td><td align="right"><em>21.161,52</em></td><td align="right"><em>-3.966,02</em></td><td align="right"><em>17.195,50</em></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
</tbody></table>
```

Update, tried that, pasted in the correct position, but did not respect the formatting of my spreadsheet

```
Sub COLAR()

Dim DataObj As MSForms.DataObject
Set DataObj = New MSForms.DataObject
DataObj.GetFromClipboard

SText = DataObj.GetText(1)

ActiveSheet.Range("A3").Select
ActiveSheet.Range("A3").Value = SText
ActiveSheet.Paste

End Sub
```

I get it, now i want the result that ive been looking, just one thing, the last column is currency value, but it is pasting text value, as I do to format it using this same vba, which is currently like this

```
Sub COLAR()

Dim DataObj As MSForms.DataObject
Set DataObj = New MSForms.DataObject
DataObj.GetFromClipboard

SText = DataObj.GetText(1)

ActiveSheet.Range("A3").Select
ActiveSheet.Range("A3").Value = SText
ActiveSheet.PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)

End Sub
```

[image: Text Format Error]

SOLVED!!! Many thanks!

Comment: Try `ActiveSheet.Range("A3").Select`, `ActiveSheet.Paste`. I think you'll have to delete the first and last row after pasting.

Comment: I tried replacing ActiveSheet.Range("A3:M90").Value = SText with ActiveSheet.Range("A3").Select, ActiveSheet.Paste , but it just pasted in the active cell range and didn't respect my spreadsheet formatting

Comment: It might make more sense to paste into a new temporary worksheet and then copy only the desired rows to the target worksheet

Comment: but it is possible to paste respecting my format?? Using the formula in the question